# Why new questions disappear when I refresh the page?

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, live-refresh, question-lists

I have noticed some weird issue that when I'm looking for new questions, if I click the box that says: `"x New questions"`, I see the new questions. But then if I refresh the page they are gone. This is really annoying, I don't know if it only happens to me, but I would like to know the reason of this.

Note: I'm using Chrome and didn't test this on other browsers so I don't know whether it's browser related.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Those new questions are delivered to you via web sockets, which lets you receive instant notifications of them.

However, the question lists themselves are still cached server-side, and reloading the page will still load that cached version of the list, without any new questions you *may have* been notified about before. They won't appear in the refreshed list until the cache updates again.

Comment: thanks, this is pretty much what I guessed.do you know how often the cache gets updated?

Comment: I don't know the *exact* schedule, but it's fairly short for question lists. About every minute or two.