# Get uncached version of "Newest Questions" feed

Tags: bug, meta, live-refresh, question-lists

I was going to ask why new questions "with new activity" disappear when refreshing the page, and found it had been [asked and answered before](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/278854/1458374).

Me not being familiar with how web sockets work, my question thus changes: Is there any way to get an *uncached* version of the list?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, there is no way to force the server's cache to reset.  Were it available, it would make the site very vulnerable to a DDoS attack.