# Stale/fake statistics for questions loaded live

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, new-nav, live-refresh

When questions are loaded in the new nav by clicking the "n new questions" notification, they are shown with blank statistics (0 score, 0 answers, 1 view). All the questions below were loaded at once, right before I took the screenshot:

[image: screenshot]

Note that even the oldest loaded question with 20+ minutes of age is shown with the same stats. Manually reloading the questions page shows the real statistics. The same in action:

[image: video screencap]

(pictured: click -> questions loaded -> mouse moved -> ctrl+r for refresh)

I'm aware that this is likely due to [how the feed works](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/278854/5067311) or that it's [status-bydesign](/questions/tagged/status-bydesign) not to query the server with these refreshes. But considering how I don't know anything about how the web works, I can't be sure. And even then I'd consider loading the fresh statistics as a feature.

Comment: Why is it (mis)designed like this?  Why do we have to refresh to get the correct information?  (And why doesn't the system keep a permanent record of how many questions we want to see on a page, but that's a separate topic of discussion.)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

In what might be the shortest official response ever, [animuson tagged the question with [status-bydesign]](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/revisions/350490/4) an hour ago. For want of any further feedback, I assume the issue is closed.

---

Quoting [a comment of animuson left on another answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/350490/stale-fake-statistics-for-questions-loaded-live/350510?noredirect=1#comment481461_350510):

> It's not that loading a handful of questions would be expensive. It's more that being able to load updated stats for that handful of questions requires opening some sort of AJAX path to get updated information for what you've collected over the web sockets. But having a path means anyone can access it at any time, for whatever purposes, which isn't something we'd be interested in maintaining. It'd essentially be like having an open call to "gather information for this list of question IDs" which is very easy to abuse since it can't be cached.

Comment: [meta-tag:status-review], [meta-tag:status-norepro], and [meta-tag:status-planned] are shorter. :-)

Comment: What do upvotes mean on this answer? Do they mean that people agree with the resolution of the original question, or that *this* is a valid, useful answer?

Comment: @anatolyg: yes.